# Strange behavior of "which" command in Matlab for Linux

Tags: linux, matlab

I am working with the Unix version of Matlab R2015a under Fedora 22. I just found that if a execute the command

```
which filename
```

when I am located in a folder different than the folder where *filename* is located, I would get the full path of *filename* **but** with an extra folder "/.". For example, suppose that the full path of *filename* that I get when I run the command in the folder where *filename* is located is

```
/home/user/Documents/MATLAB/Apps/project/filename.m
```

Then, the path that I get when I am located in a different folder would be

```
/home/user/Documents/MATLAB/Apps/project/./filename.m
```

I tested the command over R2012 in Windows and the behavior is the expected, that is, the full path name is the same no matter where you are located.

My matlabroot: `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a`

My userpath: `/home/user/Documents/MATLAB/`

In my path I have a lot of other folders, including all subfolders of userpath.

Has somebody else experienced this behavior? Any explanation or solution?

Comment: What is your `matlabroot`? It might have that `/.` at the end. It should be harmless, shouldn't it? I can't see it on Ubuntu 14.04, R2012b.

Comment: @AndrasDeak My matlabroot is `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a`

Comment: Then probably `/home/user/Matlab/.` is added to your `path`, rather than the truncated version. But maybe not: in R2012b I added a directory with this syntax, but `which` still omits the `/.` part. Does it happen with other directories as well?

Comment: @AndrasDeak In my path I have the matlabroot and `/home/user/Documents/MATLAB`, which is my userpath.

Comment: How can matlab find files in `/home/user/Matlab` if it's not on your path and you're in another directory? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @AndrasDeak That path was just an example. I didn't want to put the larger one, but I am going to add that extra information about my matlabroot and my userpath for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95758/discussion-between-carlos-mendoza-and-andras-deak).

Answer (score 3):

It may be unexpected but it is not an error:

(1) The path is still correct. "." (dot) is a reference to the directory that it contains this entry. This is required by POSIX http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html (see section 4.12) .

(2) Mathworks documentation specifies that "which" returns the "full path". It does not give a definition for "full path". In my book they are free to use a meaning of "full path" that allows "." directory self-references in the path.

Edit: As for "solution" and "explanation":

Solution: You can get rid of the extra dot directory with

```
strrep(which('filename'),'/./','/')
```

No Explanation:

Mathworks has not made the source code of their "which" function available. Therefore, only they can explain the behaviour. Contact customer support. In addition to the information you have provided so far, they might also need the output of the matlab "path" commando in your installation environment to be able to explain it.

Comment: I'm probably being picky, but I don't feel that this is a proper answer to the question. OP never indicated any distress regarding the situation, but asked "*Has somebody else experienced this behavior? Any explanation or solution?*". This is an answer to neither (OK, it does answer along the lines of "no solution needed due to lack of a problem").

Comment: OK, I agree that `/home/user/Matlab/./filename.m` is still a *correct* path, I going to erase that word from my question. However, I still do not understand why the described behavior.

Comment: The Question originally called the behaviour an error. It has been edited since. I can think of two reasons to call it an error: (1) you do not know what "." means or fear that it is not well defined, (2) behaviour differs from documentation. I addressed these points. Now extending with a solution and explain why only mathworks can explain the behaviour.

Comment: (3) I called an error because the behavior change depending of where I am located.